# jquery scrollTop issue, scrollbar remains on top, instead of staying bottom

Tags: jquery

Requirement in Chat Application, where in if a text is typed in textarea and send button is clicked, 
the msg animates/scrolls top to the area, allowing the user to see[focus is on] the last typed msg. 
I.e. The scroll bar should be on bottom.

Jquery version used now is 1.3.2 but need to change the Jquery version to 1.9.1 or above.

Code : used for scrolling

```
$("#msg").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#msg").attr("scrollHeight")-$("#msg").height() 
}, 0.001);

$('msg').scrollTop($('msg')[0].scrollHeight);
```

when jquery.js is changed to 1.92 or 1.10.* or 1.11.3 etc, the scroll bar remains on the top instead of bottom
when the typed msg is scrolled up, so that user cant see the last typed msg, instead need to scroll down every time.

Pasted the two lines of code that does the work. Please advise on how to correct the scenario.

Comment: Changed the line $('#msg').scrollTop($('#msg')[0].scrollHeight);

Answer (score 1):

Please try changing

```
$('msg').scrollTop($('msg')[0].scrollHeight);
```

to

```
$('#msg').scrollTop($('#msg')[0].scrollHeight);
```

It looks like `'#msg'` is the right selector to use going by your first line of code. `'msg'` wouldn't select anything unless you have a tag named `<msg>`.

Comment: $('#msg').scrollTop($('#msg')[0].scrollHeight); This is how the real code looks like, i have pasted without # in my question, corrected now. Please advise.